# ansible parameterised ini lookup in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use ansible to take the contents of a simple yaml file and template these into a more complex one (the `.kitchen.yml` for test-kitchen, as it happens)

My config file looks like this

```
test_platforms:
  - ubuntu-16.04
  - ubuntu-14.04
```

I would like to pass this into the `.kitchen.yml` and have the keys in `{{ test_platforms }}` associated with particular images, e.g.

```
......
platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04
    driver_config:
      image: ubuntu:16.04    <--- This is the associated image
      platform: ubuntu
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver_config:
      image: ubuntu:14.04    <--- This is the associated image
      platform: ubuntu
......
```

I thought I would be able to accomplish this with a lookup, e.g.:

```
platforms:
{% for platform in test_platforms %}
  - name: {{ platform }}       
    driver_config:
      image: {{ lookup('ini', 'test_platforms section=docker file=platforms.ini') }}
      platform: ubuntu
{% endfor %}
```

...given a `platforms.ini`:

```
[docker]
ubuntu-16.04=solita/ubuntu-systemd:16.04
ubuntu-14.04=ubuntu-upstart:14.04
```

I was hoping that I could use parameterise the lookup (i.e. the "test platforms in the jinja "for" loop would read in the list of values in the `{{ test platforms }}` variable, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a fix for this, or a better way of doing it? It seems like one of those things that someone will already have solved, but rather extensive googling by me has not turned up anything, and it doesn't seem apparent from the docs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with test-kitchen. Do you have to use `platforms.ini`? Could you put the information into an ansible variables file instead?

Comment: Just to clarify, this is an abstraction around test-kitchen. It's necessary to add a lot of boilerplate config each time you want to apply it to config mgmt code you want to test. I was tasked with building a wrapper that could automatically do this for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have some typos in your template.  In the following block:

```
platforms:
{% for platform in test_platforms %}
  - name: {{ platform }}       
    driver_config:
      image: {{ lookup('ini', 'test_platforms section=docker file=platforms.ini') }}
      platform: ubuntu
{% endfor %}
```

There are two problems:  (a) you're referencing `test_platforms` (the list of platforms) rather than `platform` (your loop variable), and (b) you're not actually substituting the value of your `platform` variable into the lookup expression.  Try this:

```
platforms:
{% for platform in test_platforms %}
  - name: {{ platform }}       
    driver_config:
      image: {{ lookup('ini', platform + ' section=docker file=platforms.ini') }}
      platform: ubuntu
{% endfor %}
```

If I have that in a file named `input.yml` and I use this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    test_platforms:
      - ubuntu-16.04
      - ubuntu-14.04
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: ./input.yml
        dest: ./output.yml
```

I get as output:

```
platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04       
    driver_config:
      image: solita/ubuntu-systemd:16.04
      platform: ubuntu
  - name: ubuntu-14.04       
    driver_config:
      image: ubuntu-upstart:14.04
      platform: ubuntu
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent almost a whole day trying to get this working! I know you're not supposed to do this on Stack Overflow, but I'm ridiculously grateful!!